# How to power nodemcu devkit using battery

Tags: esp8266, battery, nodemcu

I like software and I am comfortable writing lua code for nodemcu devkit. But I am not a hardware guy.

I need to setup the nodemcu so that it is a standalone module, ie powered by a battery. What is the best way to do this so that the whole thing is as small as possible? Which battery should I use(If I need to continuously run the nodemcu for 2 hours with wifi ON)? How to connect the battery with the nodemcu, ie any regulator needed?

Right now I am powering nodemcu via USB. I researched this in google, but couldn't find a satisfactory solution.

I am using [this](http://www.amazon.in/Lolin-NodeMCU-3-01-0268-1-NodeMCU-WiFi-Arduino-IDE-Lua-based-IoT-ESP8266-Development-Board/dp/B010O1G1ES/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1501154820&sr=8-1&keywords=nodemcu%20esp8266) nodemcu devkit

Please point me to the correct forum, if this is the wrong place to ask this question

Comment: http://www.esp8266.com/viewforum.php?f=13 would be the right place to ask in my opinion.

Comment: Any more feedback needed? Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/257994 so Stack Overflow could mark this as closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about powering hardware, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to NOT use that devkit but use one with a LiPo connector instead e.g. https://www.adafruit.com/product/2821. An alternative would be to use [WeMos D1 minis with a LiPo/battery shield](https://frightanic.com/go/wemos-store/).

If you want to stick to your devkit you "just" have to make sure you feed 3.3V to the 3.3V pin. Since batteries deliver no stable voltage over time you need to place some kind of [buck/boost converter](https://www.banggood.com/search/buck-boost-converter.html?p=PT19151269030201502M) (step-down/step-up) between the battery and the module.

You could of course also target the VIN pin which expects 5V but that would be less efficient if you used a LiPo battery. First, the external converter would boost from the LiPo's ~3.7V to 5V. Then the devkits internal converter would have to bring this down to 3.3V again.

Furthermore, if you feed the ESP8266 from batteries you want to pay attention to any power that'd be lost along the way. With the L7805 voltage regulator for example there is a constant 'quiescent' current draw of 6mA. That may be ok if your source is a power adapter but less ideal when it's a battery. Buck/boost converters are more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need it to stand alone, would you consider using a phone charger? Just simply plug in the USB cable to any phone charger that you can find. That way it will provide stable power for as long as you want.

In case you really want to use a battery. Then you will need a 7805 regulator IC. This will step down your voltage to 5V. Then direct this to Vin Pin on the NodeMCU. I believe you should get 3.3V out of the 3v3 pin.